# What is difference between an atmospheric model and a climate model?

Tags: atmosphere-modelling, climate-models

I am wondering the major differences been an Atmospheric model and a Climate model?
For example, Regional Atmospheric Modeling System (RAMS) versus Regional Climate Modeling System (RegCM). I recently use the both for 20 years climate simulations, but didn't find why one is called atmospheric and one is climate?

Comment: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/15193/conversion-of-an-nwp-model-into-climate-model

Comment: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/20/what-are-the-major-differences-between-weather-models-and-climate-models

Comment: @gansub.. none of your link answers my question. Weather model is different and quite understandable.

Comment: An atmospheric model is nothing but a weather model. You can use the weather model to simulate climate such as CWRF but a RCM is used for climate modeling. If my links do not help please wait for somebody else to answer your question.

Comment: @gansub :: Thank you . If all weather models are atmospheric models and visa versa, then your links answer my questions...